# How to edit requested params in Django Admin Page?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

By default, Django admin page basically form submitted data set to database naturally without any data edits.
However, I want to edit this.

When I develop blog to use Django admin, I have columns in table like this

```
| title | article_md | article_html
```

and I want to make `article_html` data not to edit directly in django admin page form but to generate html style data from markdown style data of `article_md` and to submit to database.

How can I do this? Is there any way to do something like generally controller in model.py or admin.py?

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    article_md = models.TextField(null=True)
    article_html = models.TextField(null=True)←I want it is generated by converting article_md's data
```

Comment: You can override the save() method to do what you want. There is plenty on Google about how to derive a value from another value in your model.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have succeeded by following!!

Answer (score 0):

model.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=255
    )
    article_md = models.TextField(
        null=True
    )
    article_html = models.TextField(
        null=True
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.article_html = markdown.markdown(self.article_md, extensions=['gfm'])
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

admin.py

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['article_html']
admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```